# Help with semi-formal logic

Tags: logic, formal-languages, formal-systems, formal-proofs

How do I write semi-formally 'there are only 2 objects in the universe'?
My hypothesis is:   ∃x∃y(x≠y) 
Any ideas?

Comment: what you wrote only says that there are at least two objects. You need to add that for each $z$, $z=x$ or $z=y$

Answer (score 1):

$\exists x \exists y \forall z ((x\neq y) \land ( (z=x) \lor (z=y))$

Comment: $\exists x \exists y (x\neq y \land \forall z( z=x \lor z=y))$ might be better.

Comment: Thanks for the remark @DanChristensen! I actually thought about it, but I prefer to keep my formulas at prenex normal form.

Comment: @DanChristensen it's usual in first order logic to say nothing about the universe in which the variables range, at least in syntactic terms. Just writing $\forall x \phi$ and requiring for all model of  the language a suitable interpretation of the symbol (that is, $M \vDash \forall x \phi$ if for all $x_0$ in the domain of the model, the formula $\phi$ with $x$ substituted by $x_0$ is a theorem, that is, $M \vDash \phi(x_0)$)

Comment: Thanks. I guess it saves having to introduce a name for your "universe" and using set theoretic notation. In mathematics, I think it is customary to explicitly limit every quantifier to some set ($U$ in the case of my suggestion).

Comment: @DanChristensen np! I had a terrible time understanding this "unbounded quantification" of first order logic (as opposed to what we are used to in ordinary mathematics), it's actually a technical difficulty sometimes. For example, when we're defining a First-Order-Theory for vector spaces we can't quantify over vectors and scalars separately and need a technical trick to get the axioms right.

Answer (score 0):

Define $a, b$ and $U$ such that 
$$a\ne b \land \forall x\in U:[x=a\lor x=b]$$

where $U$ is your *universe*.

Then recast your hypothesis as: $$\exists x\in U: \exists y\in U: x\ne y$$